# How to map enum => int solidity

Tags: enums, solidity

It's noob question, sorry...

I would like to know if possible to do something like this :

```
enum animals {CAT, DOG}
mapping(animals => int8) maps;

constructor() {
        maps[animals.CAT] = 10;
}

function decrementAnimal(string memory _animal) public {
        maps[animals._animal] -= 1;
}
```

I have this error :

`Member "_animal" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(enum Test.animals).`

I can do something like this :

```
enum animals {CAT, DOG}
mapping(animals => int8) maps;

constructor() {
        maps[animals.CAT] = 10;
        maps[animals.DOG] = 10;
}

function decrementCat() public {
        maps[animals.CAT] -= 1;
}


function decrementDog() public {
        maps[animals.DOG] -= 1;
}
```

but it seems not optimised....

Thanks all for your replies,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is the following:

```
enum Animal {CAT, DOG}
mapping(Animal => int8) maps;

constructor() {
        maps[Animal.CAT] = 10;
}

function decrementAnimal(Animal _animal) public {
        maps[_animal] -= 1;
}
```

You can simply pass the enum type as the parameter of the function you are trying to call.